# Copy a File to rails project folder using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am in the middle of developing a gem for rails and i stuck with this issue. My logic is I have a gem created, and the gem installed to my local machine. What I need is when I type `gem_name --install`, there is a file called `test.rb` should be copied to inside a `rails project/ config/initializers/`. The file to be copied is currently placed in a folder in my gem. I have tried

```
Dir.pwd
```

but it is not give me results as expected. Please find a solution for me and TIA..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a rails gem you would use a generator together with a "template" file.

```
class FooGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

  def copy_initializer_file
    copy_file "initializer.rb", "config/initializers/#{file_name}.rb"
  end
end
```

This will would copy the file when the user of the gem runs `rails generate foo`.

Make sure to read through the rails guides sections [on generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) and [creating engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) as there are quite a few gotchas and conventions.

Comment: i have a question, if i type gem-abc --install, is this going to copy the file to inside the rails  project folder where the gem to be installed ?